# cannot fetch data with ajax get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mongodb

I have setup a mongo database. For now I have just one id in my database. I am trying to fetch the data in my javascript file ( using ImpactJS engine ) with an ajax get request.

Below is how my database looks like for now. Its on mongo db. Very basic for testing purposes

```
{
  "_id": "5303a4d4c4fd447a0a7fb528",
  "__v": 0,
  "ans": "ans",
  "hint": "Hints.",
  "score": 20,
  "name": "ABC",
  "pid": 1
}
```

I then use an Ajax request in my javascript file to fetch the "ans" field from the database. Below is my code for the same

```
getQuestionAnswer:function(){
             var requestURL = "http://128.2.238.182:3000/problem?pid=".concat(this.passedQsId);
             var answer;
             $.ajax({
                 type:'GET',
                 url: requestURL,
                 async: false,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(data) {
                     answer = data.ans;
                 },
                 error: function(data) {
                     answer = "<p>ERROR</p>";
                 }
             })
             return answer;
    },
```

The URL is passed correctly, I double checked it on my logs. However when I try to use this request function in my other function, i get infinte number of errors saying "NS ERROR FAILURE" or something. Below is the line of code where I get the error message

```
 checkAnswer: function(id){
         var correctAnswer = this.getQuestionAnswer();
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am totally new to javascript and web programming in general. This is kind of a challenge for me as I have mostly been coding in Java, C++!

Comment: try - **dataType: 'jsonp'**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: I get this error after changing it to jsonp               SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
"_id": "5303a4d4c4fd447a0a7fb528",

Comment: please can you paste me the final result of **requestURL**

Comment: under the line **var requestURL="..**, add **window.open(requestURL);** - what's in the address bar of the new window ?

Comment: {
  "_id": "5303a4d4c4fd447a0a7fb528",
  "__v": 0,
  "ans": "ans",
  "hint": "Hints.",
  "score": 20,
  "name": "ABC",
  "pid": 1
}
This is my mongodb collection which shows up on the URL
"http://128.2.238.182:3000/problem?pid=".concat(this.passedQsId);
concat is to pass the id to the URL.. because we plan to have several pid's .. for eg pid=1, pid=2, pid=3.... etc

Comment: If you are having issues seeing the collection in my previous comment then I request you to check the same at the very top of my initial question. Thank you so much for your help till now

Comment: let me check that once again. It could be

Comment: Sorry, you are saying it works when you go direct ?

Comment: I don't think so. I spoke to my db guy and he says it should be fine
To retrieve the info from the database, you use the below URL
"http://128.2.238.182:3000/problem?pid=x" (x=1,2,3)
So setting the pid value to 1,2,3 gives me all the different fields info in my collection

Comment: Yes it works on our server when I just paste the URL on my browser

Comment: Where are you reading these errors from ? The browser console ? firebug / chrome dev tools ?

Comment: Also  before the line **return answer;** add a semicolon to close the ajax call.  --- **});**

Comment: I am reading this errors from firebug.
After changing the datatype to jsonp, I got rid of the first error.
Then I just tried removing the port 3000 from my URL and it got rid of the semicolon error but now my data is returning null

Comment: After setting "answer = data.ans" and returning the answer in my ajax call,  I am expecting a value of "ans" which is the value set in my database but I get null output

Comment: cool, ajax services often require the jsonp. Looks like got a few syntax problems and might be there.

Comment: before the line **return answer** , please can you add **console.log(data);**, what does that give us ?

Comment: You need the port in the url ( if that is where the service is running from ) , that's not the semi colon it was complaining about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a little large for comments - here are some things to sort in the function

```
getQuestionAnswer:function(){
             var requestURL = "http://128.2.238.182:3000/problem?pid=".concat(this.passedQsId);
             var answer;
             $.ajax({
                 type:'GET',
                 url: requestURL,
                 dataType: 'jsonp', /* different domains often require jsonp */
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(data) {
                     console.log(data); /* check */
                     answer = data.ans;
                     return answer; /* needs to be here */
                 },
                 error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                     console.log(xhr);
                     answer = "<p>ERROR</p>";
                     return answer; /* needs to be here *
                 }
             }); 
                 /* ^ semi colon ending here */

             /* return answer; */ 
            /* removed - will not return the 'answer' 
            as the function is now Asynchronous */

    },
```

**Update:** with example looking at the wider function and example `callback`

```
var answerfunctions = { 
    getQuestionAnswer : function(callback){ /* here accepts the callback function */
             var requestURL = "http://128.,,etc";
             var answer;
             $.ajax({
                 type:'GET',
                 url: requestURL,
                 dataType: 'jsonp',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(data) {
                     callback(data.ans);
                 },
                 error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                     console.log(xhr);
                     callback("ERROR");
                 }
             }); 
    }

 };

/* call the function and pass a function as an argument to callback to */
answerfunctions.getQuestionAnswer(function(datareturn) { alert(datareturn); });
```

Comment: Thanks again. There was still the semicolon error which I somehow removed by removing the port number from the URL but I am not sure if that is correct.
I made all the changes as you mentioned but the answer value still returns null  when I call it in my other function :(

Comment: You need the port in the url , or does it run without the port number ?

Comment: I have updated the code to give a more meaning error response and a way to see what the out of 'data' is before you **return**

Comment: Darn, I cannot test my code as the database server is temporarily down. But I think, I am not sure, the problem is me calling the getQuestionAnswer() function in another function. Somehow its not able to fetch the value. Would callback function solve the problem? I am new to callback functions in general so I don't have a lot of idea on that topic

Comment: Probally good if you can post more of the code to the question, will check in tomorrow

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. The code works fine now. There was a problem in our db server, some cross domain issue. We fixed it. Thanks